# $targetResource parameter in PingFederate

Tags: pingfederate

Is it possible to use the `$targetResource` parameter in `idp.logout.success.page.template.html`? Is there any other way to send a URL from the log-off application to PF log-off success page?

Configurations:  I'm using the HTML Form IDP adapter logout and configured my HTML Form IDP adapter Log-out URL (`https://localhost:9031/ext/logout`) as my IDP SLO service URL and I'm using the following URL to trigger IDP Initiated SLO:
`https://localhost:9031/idp/startSLO.ping?TargetResource=htp://172.25.242.205:8005/index`.

The Log-off option is working fine and I can see the `idp.logout.success.page.template.html` template rendered successfully.

I have customized this page for our standards but we have one dynamic URL in log-off success page as hyperlink. (I plan to send this hyperlink URL from our application as TargetResource parameter with IDP initiated SLO URL but its not capturing in `idp.logout.success.page.template.html`)

E.g.:
`https://localhost:9031/idp/startSLO.ping?TargetResource=http://172.25.242.205:8005/index`

Answer (score 0):

[TargetResource in SLO](https://documentation.pingidentity.com/pingfederate/pf80/index.shtml#concept_idpEndpoints.html#concept_idpEndpoints) is intended to be the location that PingFed redirects the browser to after a successful SLO. The query parameter will not be forwarded to the logout success template. The only thing that I can suggest is that you set a cookie, and use Velocity to retrieve/work with that cookie to do what it is you desire.

Comment: Just for clarification, Since i could not hardcode(our app specification) any logout service in SP side 
i configured adapter log off url(ext/logout) in IDP SLO service.
Any way i am issuing IDP/startSLO.ping URL for my log-off with TargetResource parameter (Know can use adapter log-off URL independently but wants to use TargetResource param).
In this case PF redirect to adapter log-off URL only and displayed adpater log-off template not to our TargetResource URL. i believe this way PF can work. Am i correct? or Still PF can redirect to TargetResource?

Comment: Sorry, missed this.... If you set a logoff URL for the form adapter then it overrides the target resource.